# Android Wear Need to show notification on wear when the device is getting paired to wear

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-notification

Please say how we can show notification on android as soon as the wear is paired to device, like the weather notification from google.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom capability on the phone. Your wearable would listen to this capability with a `WearableListenerService`: override `onCapabilityChanged`. When the phone connects to the wearable, the capabilities provided by reachable nodes (from the watch) are updated and onCapabilityChanged is called.

See the documentation [Advertise and Retrieve capability](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html#SendMessage).

Advertise : (res/values/wear.xml) (mobile resources)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="android_wear_capabilities">
        <item>my_phone_capability</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Listen to changes on reachable capabilities : (WearableListenerService, service declared in the manifest with intent action `BIND_LISTENER`)

```
@Override
public void onCapabilityChanged(CapabilityInfo capabilityInfo) {
    String mPhoneNodeId = pickBestNodeId(capabilityInfo.getNodes());
    // you can check if it's the capability you want (my_phone_capability)
    if (mPhoneNodeId == null) {
        // phone is disconnected
    } else {
        // phone is connected, send notif
    }
}
```